# How to match up to second letter using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I match "22A00" in the following string: "22A00B20A" using a regular expression?

Comment: Why a regex? Following what logic? You need to spell out a rule. The first numbers? The first 2 characters? Everything up to "A"?

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
/^[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*/
```

Explanation:

```
^          Start of line
[^a-zA-Z]* Zero or more non-letters
[a-zA-Z]   A letter
[^a-zA-Z]* Zero or more non-letters
```

Regular expressions are greedy by default so this ensure that it will find the longest match. If there is no second letter it will match the entire string. If there is no first letter it will fail to match. If this isn't what you want then please specify what should happen in these special cases.

You may also want to consider what you mean by "letter". This regular expression won't match foreign letters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about that literal string

```
if( /22A00/.test("22A00B20A") )
    // match
```

otherwise, look to @Marks answer